# Titanium Images Wrong Size

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a Titanium app where I am using the same ImageView for alot of different images. I am changing the image in the image view by setting it's image property.

The problem is some of the images are not showing at their full size sometimes, it is kinda random, but sometimes they show full size sometimes not.

I have width and height set to "auto" on the image view.

Anyone come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially more reliable way would be too dynamically resize the image before handing it off to the ImageView by using [Titanium.Blob.imageAsReized](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsResized).

Try to integrate this in your code, first you have to load the image as a blob though.

```
// Get the blob of your image first, then call this method
imageView.image = imageBlob.imageAsResized(newWidth, newHeight);
```

Comment: I am developing for Android, so it seems this will not work. I may have come across a solution, by getting the images width, height first then setting the width, height of ImageView respectively. Seems to work so far.

Comment: Yeah imageAsResized only works for iOS, but constraining to the height should hopefully make it resize correctly by itself.

Comment: Imagefactory module has many functions for image manipulations and it works for android too: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1184?918086764